# How to count the number of zeros in Python?

Tags: list, python-2.7, count

My code is currently written as:

```
convert = {0:0,1:1,2:2,3:3,4:0,5:1,6:2,7:1}
rows = [[convert[random.randint(0,7)] for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(5)]
numgood = 25 - rows.count(0)

print numgood
>> 25
```

It always comes out as 25, so it's not just that rows contains no 0's.

Comment: Convert changes the values so everything is between 0 and 3. It allows me to add a probability to how often the numbers appear.

Comment: `rows` doesn't contain any zeroes, though.

Comment: How do you mean? 0 is one of the 8 numbers it can generate.

I just tested it: `>>> random.randint(0,7)` came out as `0`.

Comment: But `rows` is made up of *lists*, not integers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you printed `rows`?

It's `[[0, 1, 0, 0, 2], [1, 2, 0, 1, 2], [3, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 3, 2, 0, 1]]`, so you have a nested list there.

If you want to count the number of `0`'s in those nested lists, you could try:

```
import random

convert = {0:0, 1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:0, 5:1, 6:2, 7:1}
rows = [[convert[random.randint(0, 7)] for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(5)]

numgood = 25 - sum(e.count(0) for e in rows)
print numgood
```

**Output:**

```
18
```

Comment: I like how the code looks compared to DSM's. Thanks. If you wouldn't mind, could you link me to the documentation for `for` and `in`?

Comment: [Here](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) in the Python Tutorial, or search on Google "`for` in Python" or "`in` in Python". You also should read more about "list comprenhension"

Answer (score 3):

`rows` doesn't contain any zeroes; it contains lists, not integers.

```
>>> row = [1,2,3]
>>> type(row)
<type 'list'>
>>> row.count(2)
1
>>> rows = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
>>> rows.count(2)
0
>>> rows.count([1,2,3])
1
```

To count the number of zeroes in any of the *lists* in rows, you could use a generator expression:

```
>>> rows = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6], [0,0,8]]
>>> sum(x == 0 for row in rows for x in row)
2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use numpy:

```
import numpy as np
import random

convert = {0:0,1:1,2:2,3:3,4:0,5:1,6:2,7:1}
rows = [[convert[random.randint(0,7)] for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(5)]
numgood = 25 - np.count_nonzero(rows)

print numgood
```

Output:

```
9
```